# awk: reformat date in a list of data-files (mass edit)

Tags: awk

I want to awk a list of data-files. All records - there is an unknown number of records before - before , e.g.,

```
/10-12-2014 06:47:59/{p=1}
```

are to be skipped.

A brief template of one data file looks like this:

data_file_001

```
0; n records to be skipped
1;10-12-2014 06:47:59;
2;12-12-2014 10:17:44;
3;12-12-2014 10:37:44;
4;14-12-2014 10:00:32;
5;;movefield
6;16-12-2014 04:15:39;
```

needed Output ($2 datefield reformatted and $3 moved to $4):

```
colnum;date;col3;col4;col5
2;12.12.14;;
3;12.12.14;;
4;14.12.14;;
5;;;movefield;moved
6;16.12.14;;
```

My source file is this at the moment:

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS=";" ; print "colnum;date;col3;col4;col5"}
FNR == 1 { p=0 }

$3 == "movefield" { $4 = $3; $5 = "moved";  $3 = ""}
   #(x=index($2," ") > 0) {DDMMYY = substr($2,1,x-1)}
$2=substr($2,1,11)

p!=0{print};
/10-12-2014 06:47:59/{p=1}
```

I have problems to reformat the data fields: The pattern-action (x=index($2," ") > 0) {DDMMYY = substr($2,1,x-1)} does not work nor $2=substr($2,1,11) in conjunction with the movefield action. Notice that the record where the movefield field appears has no date field.

Please have in mind that the awk is meant to be used on a bunch of files (loop).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for implace editing, no loop required:

```
awk -i inplace '
   BEGIN { OFS=FS=";" ; print "colnum","date","col3","col4","col5" }
   FNR==1 { next }
   $3 == "movefield" { $4 = $3; $5 = "moved";  $3 = ""; print; next }
   { sub(/ .*/,"",$2); gsub(/-/,".",$2); print $0, ""}
' file*
```

Comment: Wonderful! You also gsubbed the - into . in the datefield. I forgot to mention that, and I had problems with that in my 'loop' attempt. I did not know about the inplace 'function' and will have to look for it in the manual. Improvment is needed for FNR==1 { next } I think. I had the loop since there is an unknown number of records in the datafiles before I need to process. As example I gave the certain date /10-12-2014 06:47:59/{p=1}

Comment: So, all records before "10-12-2014 06:47:59" need to be skipped.

Comment: I can not use the code above. I use gawk and Windows shell. I do not know how to enter the programm code excactly as given. It seems I have to use it like in the manual: awk -f program.awk file*.csv But then I do not know how to call it with -i inplace. It gives me errors.

Comment: You would call it like: `awk -i inplace -f program.awk file*` Inplace edit was introduced in (about) version 4.1.0.

Comment: Add your extra requirements (e.g. whatever `Improvement is needed for FNR==1 { next } I think` means and `all records before "10-12-2014 06:47:59" need to be skipped`) to your question. wrt `Why does my loop not work with $2=substr($2,1,11) ` - what loop and what were you hoping that statement would do?

Comment: Ok, that should be the explanation. I am on gawk-3.1.6.exe

Comment: @Morton As stated the program is to be used on x-files in a folder. I thought loop is the right term when the program processes a bunch of datafiles and starts each time again with its pattern-action matching. So $2=substr($2,1,11) was meant to shorten the datafield and to eventually gsub - to . Anyhow I will open a new question.

Comment: That's a VERY old version of gawk (5+ years out of date) and doesn't support inplace editing. Get a new gawk.

Answer (score 1):

Another in GNU awk:

```
$ awk '
function refmt(str) {                   # reformat date for comparing
    split(str,d,"[ :-]")
    return mktime(d[3] " " d[2] " " d[1] " " d[4] " " d[5] " " d[6])
} 
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
    start=refmt("10-12-2014 06:47:59")  # reformat the threshold date
    print "colnum","date","col3","col4" # print header (why 5?)
} 
refmt($2)>start || $2=="" {             # if date > start or empty
    sub(/ .*/,"",$2)                    # delete time part
    gsub(/-/,".",$2)                    # replace - by .
    $4=$3; $3=""                        # or $3 = OFS $3
    print                               # output
}' file
colnum;date;col3;col4
2;12.12.2014;;
3;12.12.2014;;
4;14.12.2014;;
5;;;movefield
6;16.12.2014;;
```

Comment: Mr Brown, I got the date fields reformatted this way. It is even working on a bunch of datafiles. This is now the prestep before  I run a 2nd awk programm over them.

Comment: Nice. What is the 2nd program?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I am still writing it. There is a lot of reorganization to be done. Of course it would be nice to have only one program but after having spent the whole day now I going over with a 2nd program tomorrow. Later I could post it over here..

Comment: Sorry, but I am missing it. Can you show me please  how to change the pattern-matching  of the line "10-12-2014 06:47:59? The reformatting of all time-fields is fine but I need another 'break-point' from where to process all files. The time given above is only one example and I thought it would be fine to clarify the issue. In general, practicable would be to match $1=="0" or $2=="n records to be skipped" then process all following lines. Thank you!

Comment: Change the timestamp in here: `start=refmt("10-12-2014 06:47:59")`. `refmt()` returns the epoch time for the timestamp which is stored to var `start` against which all the other reformated timestamps are compared against (`refmt($2)>start || $2==""`).

Comment: I think we are misunderstand each other or more likely I do not get it. - In my real datafiles the matching record is a string like "date of xy". So, in each file the record "date of xy" appears. And all lines above/before this record and the line that contains the record "date of xy" are to be skipped. Then I ned to reformat the timestamps and other things. I am sorry, that it is so complex to explain for me.

Comment: Make another question, post the data and expected output.

Comment: ok, I will do so. Thank you. May be this is sufficient? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061149/awk-pattern-match-substr-field-action-issue?noredirect=1#comment77100115_45061149  I do not want to spam stackoverflow with to many similar questions.